# How can I assign the raw Name of an S3 bucket to a variable and then use that variable

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a an S3 bucket and then use that bucket in another AWS service:

I'm doing this way:

I have a variable named $AccountAlias which I'll use that to make my buckets unique, so I'm running this:

```
bucketName=$(aws s3 mb s3://mytestbkt-${AccountAlias})
```

The bucket is created successfully, but I'm expecting that $bucketName will store the Name of the bucket, then use that variable to another service that expects the Bucket Name:

```
aws shield associate-drt-log-bucket --log-bucket $bucketName
```

After running this command I get the error:

```
make_bucket:: command not found    
aws: error: argument --log-bucket: expected one argument
```

And It makes sense, because if I run `echo $bucketName` I get: `make_bucket: mytestbkt-testacc123`

So, How can I assign just the value of the bucket name to my variable to use that in another CLI command?

Comment: `aws s3 mb` returns something like `make_bucket: example-bucket`, you'll need to filter out the `make_bucket: `, or better yet, just assign the variable of the bucket you want to make, then use that variable to make the bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable for the bucket name initially and then use it in both places:

```
#!/bin/bash
bucketName="mytestbkt-$AccountAlias"
aws s3 mb "s3://$bucketName"
aws shield associate-drt-log-bucket --log-bucket "$bucketName"
```